# Lost reference created window after surfing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have creating a new browser window `win` by `#new-window-id`click. And I have events system with that window. Closing `win.closed` for example. Everything is work until I go to links inside the created window.

```
 $('#new-window-id').on('click', function(){

                var finalUrl = $(this).attr('href');
                var win = window.open(
                    finalUrl,
                    'fullWindowMode');

                console.log('created '+ win.name);
                var timer = setInterval(function() {

                    if(win.closed) {
                        console.log('closed '+ finalUrl);
                        clearInterval(timer);

                        document.getElementById('#iframeID').contentWindow.location.reload();
                    }


                }, 1000);

            });
```

So I have iframe on main page. I want to open it in a new window and edit a content there. Then after closing created window, my main page iframe should be updated.

> Steps:
>
> 1. Click the link `#new-window-id`/ //window is opened.
> 2. Close window. `win.closed` is work!

When doesn't work

> Steps:
>
> 1. Click the link `#new-window-id`/ //window is opened.
> 2. In the window edit blog post. (url was changed)
> 3. Close window. event `win.closed` doesn't work!

But it breaks if I surfing inside created window. Exists way to keep this connection?

Comment: I did the following:
1. Created a window `let w = window.open('http://ya.ru')`
2. Navigated in that window (within the same site)
3. Checked `w.closed` in the main window (`false`)
4. Then closed the popup and checked again (`true`).

Looks like `w.closed` works even after navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following:
1. Created a window `let w = window.open('http://ya.ru')`
2. Navigated in that window (within the same site)
3. Checked `w.closed` in the main window (`false`)
4. Then closed the popup and checked again (`true`).

Looks like `w.closed` works even after navigation.

But if you navigate to another origin in the new window, then `location.reload()` will become inaccessible from the main window.